# How to make an item revert back to its original position on drag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So far I've got this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .addClass("choppedonion")
                .find("section")
                .html("");
        }
    });
});
```

But I would also like it to revert back to its original position when dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQueryUI sites give you an example of that: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#revert

Just set the revert option to true:

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
    revert: true,
    drag: function() {},
});
```